Multicollinearity and estimation of correlation between time series in fMRI data
I have a fMRI data consisting of a set of time series for activity of each region of brain. There is a concept called functional connectivity which shows how activity of each region depend on other regions. A common method to estimate the connectivity is the correlation.
My question is, how can I distinguish between direct connection of two regions from indirect connection of those regions through a third region.
The answer seems to be the partial correlation, but here there is not any control variable.

First off, this doesn't really have anything to do with multicollinearity as the title and tag seems to indicate. Multi-collinearity arises when multiple variables are entered into a regression model, where often by consequence of being heavily correlated, one variable obfuscates the theoretical impact of another. Your question is more just about how to get a correlation with respect to three different variables, which isn't the same thing.
On to the meat of your question. I'm not sure what you mean by this statement:

The answer seems to be the partial correlation, but here there is not any control variable.

Partial correlation by definition controls for the influence of another variable in a way similar to multiple linear regression. So there is nothing special going on in terms of control variables. Each disentangles the effect of the association of two variables after accounting for a third (or an entire subset of variables other than $x$ and $y$).
I think the biggest issue here is that because these are time series data, you would probably have to account for the autocorrelated and erratic behavior of such data. For this, you may need to consider a partial cross correlation function between the time series rather than a typical partial correlation.

The set of time series can be viewd as samples of a random vector over time, and the functional connectivity indicates how much each element of this vector can be explained by other elements, hence we have a multivariate multiple regression here (general linear model), and this was the connection between these concepts, at least in my mind.

If you have the 3rd region, and sufficient data, then the model R_1 ~ R_2 + R_3 will give of region 2 or 3 on region 1, controlled for the other. So if R_2 is associated with R_1, but only because R_3 partially effects R_2 and R_1, then the effect of R_2 on R_1 controlling for R_3 will be 0.
"Mostly Harmless Econometrics" is a good book on this if you are up for the math.
